# Как предотвратить горизонтальное переполнение контейнера текстом, при этом соблюсти грамматику в HTML?

Tags: html, css, текст

Не знаю точной статистики, но по-моему среднестатистическое русское слово длиннее среднестатистического английского. Основной проблемой является проблема переноса слов.

- Если мы сделаем `word-break: break-all`, то слова начнут переноситься где попало, да ещё и без знака переноса, что с точки зрения русской орфографии недопустимо.
- Если же мы обойдёмся `word-break: break-all`, то может произойти переполнение контейнера:

```css
.Sample {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: aliceblue;

}
```

```html
<div class="Sample">
  Этот тект не рекомендуется читать тем, у кого боязнь длинных слов - гиппопотомонстросескипедалофобия. Аланинаминотрансфераза показывает степень раззушенности печени, а aспартатаминотрансфераза - также клеток миокарда. Semtex A1 включает в себя порядка 75% тетранитропентаэритрита, а Semtex H - порядка 40%.
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как же быть?

Comment: чем плох тэг <br>?

Comment: Можете использовать hyphens: auto, но поддержка браузеров плохая

Comment: можно воспользоваться [свойством `hyphens`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Text/Wrapping_Text#adding_hyphens) и руками расставить возможные переносы. С не английским языком это свойство пока не очень автоматически работает

Comment: @Prog, отсутствием адаптивности. Резиновая/адаптивная вёрстка - де факто стандарт для современности.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

при нынешнем развитии русского, html и браузерных словарей вариантов видется немного.

1. вручную долбаться с `<wbr>`, `&shy;` приправляя этот треш word-break`ами и его аналогами.
2. сокращать или избегать использования длинных слов.
3. выносить длинные слова в отдельные широкие блоки.
4. не использовать узкие блоки.
5. писать свои словари сокращений и прикреплять их к статьям(хз как это делается и вообще возможно ли, не изучал сей вопрос вплотную, но в описании ~word-break`а кажется на htmlbook.ru попадались упоминания вставки словарей. если это работает и слов немного, это будет вполне годным выходом).
6. пробовать извращаться со вставками типа `<object data='text.pdf'>` или `<object data='text.txt'>` да и вообще любых текстовых форматов, мб что-то да получится.
7. не использовать языки с многобуквенными словами.... :3
8. забить на текущую грамматику переносов и ждать выход обновления. все таки и русский и html - живые языки, а в живых языках редко используемые, игнорируемые и неадекватные правила порой меняются, заменяются или отмирают. ту же букву "Ё" кажется в начале нулевых отменяли, потом вроде вернули зачем-то(если что не лингвист, просто слышал где-то).

> чем плох `<br>`

хотя бы тем, что он вообще не для дробления слов на части предназначен, для этих целей `<wbr>` есть.